# firefox addon page-mod - when url doesn't match

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to be able to activate a widget if a url matches some pattern, but  the problem is I also want to disable the widget when page-mod rule doesn't match the url.
So if I have few tabs open and if I switch between them I should be able to somehow disable the widget if an active tab's url doesn't match the rule, or in other case activate it. The state of widget(on/off) should be changed on loading pages and switching through tabs.

I've been struggling with this for a while and still haven't found a solution.

This is where I'm at right now:

```js
// Activates on matching one of the site domains, but I also want to deactivate
// it when it does not match 
var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
    include: ["*.site1.com","*.site2.com"], 
    onAttach: function() {
        alert("Widget activated!");
    });
});
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do then `page-mod` is the wrong solution - you simply want to listen to the active tab. Use [`tabs` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/addon-kit/docs/tabs.html) for that, listen to `ready` (new URL loaded) and `activate` (active tab changed) events:

```js
var tabs = require("tabs");
tabs.on("ready", function(tab)
{
  if (tab == tabs.activeTab)
    updateActiveTab(tab);
});
tabs.on("activate", function(tab)
{
  updateActiveTab(tab);
});
```

Your `updateActiveTab()` function would need to check `tab.url` and activate or deactivate the widget then. If you want to use patterns for that like the ones you specify for `page-mod` then you need to use the internal [`match-pattern` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/api-utils/docs/match-pattern.html), like this:

```js
var {MatchPattern} = require("match-pattern");
var patterns = [
  new MatchPattern("*.site1.com"),
  new MatchPattern("*.site2.com")
];

function updateActiveTab(tab)
{
  var matches = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++)
    if (patterns[i].test(tab.url))
      matches = true;
  if (matches)
    activateWidget();
  else
    deactivateWidget();
}
```

But of course you can just use a regular expression or something like this to test `tab.url`, you don't have to use the `match-pattern` module.

*Disclaimer*: The code examples are only there to make the approach easier to understand, they haven't been tested.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I wanted to do, and I figured it out in a meantime :D.. Thank you for your help!